# How to get join results using backbeam Android SDK?

Tags: android

I am using [backbeam](http://backbeam.io/) as a back-end and implementing [backbeam's android sdk](http://backbeam.github.io/content/android-sdk.html).

I want to performing joins to get results. I am using below code from the documentation for getting [Join Results](http://backbeam.github.io/content/android-objects.html):

```
Backbeam.select("place")
.setQuery("join last 10 events")
.fetch(100, 0, new FetchCallback() {

  @Override
  public void success(List<BackbeamObject> objects,
    int totalCount, boolean fromCache) {
    // pick a place (in real code check the objects.size() first)
    BackbeamObject place = objects.get(0);
    JoinResult join = place.getJoinResult("events");

    List<BackbeamObject> events = join.getResults();
    int count = join.getCount();
  }
});
```

I'm getting exact count of join relationship using `getCount()`. But an issue is, Join Result's `List size is always returned '0'` in `getResults()`.

Please help me. I'm stuck over here.